# Android TV Device Administration: Not Possible?

Tags: android, mdm, android-tv, nexus-player

I'm trying to install an MDM solution in a Nexus Player and it seems to error out with a `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException` when launching the intent to  `android.app.action.ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN` as per [Device Administration docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html).

Is this not supported in Android TV, so there's no way for corporate management over Nexus Player or similar devices?

Comment: I don't see any Device Administration feature in my Android TV. Probably, it can't.

Comment: I am attempting to develop a new application that needs Device Administration and am running into the same issue.  As far as I can tell there is no way to use this API and the lack of support in Android TV does not seem to be documented anywhere.